# How to pass Props in nested React Functional Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a react.js application where I have two components as shown in the attached picture. Here's the picture to make this explanation a bit clear.
[View Image](https://ibb.co/RNVkYKd)

I have a component **ProfileScreen** which has three components to be rendered in an applet.
I'm using `{children}` keyword in ProfileScreen component to render multiple components based on Click events.

```
<div className='mt-10 ml-10 mr-10'>
   <div className="flex-row-fluid ml-lg-8">
      {children}
   </div>
</div>
```

and in **UpdateProfileScreen** component, I'm using the **ProfileScreen** as follows:

```
<ProfileScreen>
    /*User Information here.*/
</ProfileScreen>
```

I'm getting the User information from redux store in UpdateProfileScreen, UpdatePasswordScreen and SavedCardScreen component. So **ProfileScreen** is just providing me a container to render ***UpdateProfileScreen***, ***UpdatePasswordScreen*** and ***SavedCardScreen***. I want to take more use of **ProfileScreen** so that other components being rendered inside this component can also use data from **ProfileScreen** rather than each component getting the userProfile state individually.
How do I pass the userProfile data to eacch one of the component?

Thank you.

Comment: You can create a context that will provide userProfile to all child components. Take a look at documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use context API to pass props to any child components that may to deep inside in the component tree, it will also simplify the props drilling part.
The document you can prefer: [enter link description here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)